# A file which is not a dir nor a file

Tags: linux, shell, file-permissions, ls, rm

This may look like a weird question, but I just got this output for a file (directory?) in my system. This may be a trivial or well-known error, but for me, this file (directory?) called `ksmserver.notifyrc` is a mystery.

```
[orly at kde-workspace on master]$ rm -fv /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc                                   2:06
rm: cannot remove `/home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc': Is a directory

[orly at kde-workspace on master]$ rm -rfv /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc                                  2:09
rm: cannot remove `/home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc/kscreenlocker.notifyrc': Permission denied

[orly at kde-workspace on master]$ ls -al /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc                                   2:09
ls: cannot access /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc/kscreenlocker.notifyrc: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc/.: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? kscreenlocker.notifyrc

[orly at kde-workspace on master]$ sudo rm -rfv  /home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc                            2:09
[sudo] password for orly: 
removed `/home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc/kscreenlocker.notifyrc'
removed directory: `/home/orly/ksmserver.notifyrc'
```

What I'd like to understand is,

1. What is `ksmserver.notifyrc` - a file or a directory?
2. Why does ls display question marks instead of attributes?
3. Why does ls list the contents of that file (directory?), but no further?

This is the first time I encounter such kind of output from ls. Any advice is really appreciated!

Fedora Linux 64bit, latest stable release.

Is this maybe a corrupted fs in need of an fsck?

Comment: Now why is this question voted down? Is it invalid? Why was the fsck notice removed? See, if I'm asking a question, that means I know little about the possible answer! I'm adding the fsck question back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a directory where you have read permissions (You can access the directory entry on the file system) but you don't have execute permissions so you can't list it's contents.
Then you have read access to the `kscreenlocker.notifyrc` file but to list any information about it you need execute permissions on the containing dir.

To recreate the situation do this:

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ touch testdir/testfile
$ chmod -x testdir
$ ls -al testdir

ls: cannot access testdir/testfile: Permission denied
ls: cannot access testdir/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access testdir/.: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? testfile
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you :) I'll consult Stevens & Rago for further information.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)what is "ksmserver.notifyrc" - a file or a dir?

It is a file, hence the `-` in the first column.

> 2)why does ls display question marks instead of attributes? 3)why does ls list the contents of that file (dir?), but no further?

You do not have execute permissions on the directory that contains it, therefore can only get minimal information about the contents.

Answer (score -2):

1. It is a directory.
2. I believe it didn't even had read access to the directory (something like that).
3. See #2. I suppose it's one of these weird permission interactions.

It would have been interesting to know the permissions of `ksmserver.notifyrc` itself.